# Customer Community accessing OWD: Private records not in Sharing Set with Data Raptor

Tags: apex, vlocity, sharing-sets, data-raptor

I have an Experience Cloud Site with users with a Customer Community license.

We are using Vlocity Data Raptors to load data. We have records that are `OWD, External: Private`

However, some records we cannot add to [Sharing Sets](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?language=en_US&id=sf.networks_setting_light_users.htm&type=5), for example, `Premises` or `Inventory Item`.

Is our only option is replace the Data Raptors with Apex code that is running in System Mode, `without sharing`?